# What percentage of ArcGIS users are using version 10.1 already?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, python-addin

I'm planning on building an add-in using ArcPy, but some of the functionality I need is only available in 10.1. I want to distribute this add-in and was wondering if making it 10.1 only would limit adoption.
So would like to know what percentage of ArcGIS users are using version 10.1 already?

Comment: I would doubt if there's an official statistic available...Normally enterprise customers, or customers with multiple interfaces linked to/from GIS would be the slowest to adopt the new versions, as it means a major work to get things upgraded. Standalone installations would be the quickest to adopt any new upgrade/service pack.

Comment: Is there no workaround for your requirement in v10? Would it be possible for you share what you're trying to achieve? I would suggest build it for latest version first...and it would be the version people would start moving to.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. If you were to shoot from the hip, what would you say the adoption rate was?

Comment: I agree with @ujjwalesri that the larger sites are the slowest to upgrade.  I know of at least 2 large oil corporations still on 9.3.1.  With that in mind, have you identified your target market for your add-in?  Does that market consist more of large enterprises, or small single installations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one else seems prepared to take a stab at this one so I'll "upgrade" my Comment to be an Answer.

It's really hard to say but I think it would be in the range of 50-70% for Desktop (Server would be lower than Desktop because its installation is recommended first).

I target 10.1 for anything I am doing, and if it also applies to 10.0 (which it almost always does) then I consider it a bonus.

One way to derive some semi useful stats may be to use the Stack Exchange API (like Bill Dollins [**did**](http://gis.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/carving-up-gis-stackexchange/) for a different purpose) to graph the change in ratio of arcgis-10.1 to arcgis-10.0 tags over time.  More questions should roughly indicate more use.

Comment: I'm not sure about your last paragraph above. I'd say that Stack Exchange is used more by developers than actual users. There's a huge time lag before "the great unwashed" actually start using this stuff

Comment: Would be interesting to know user:developer ratio on Stack Exchange GIS but I think it may be surprisingly high.